# Visual Flow: How to set Date field to Null / Blank?

Tags: flow, visual-workflow

I can't figure out how to do this.  There seems to be no global constant for blank/null associated with Date fields.  If I attempt to add {!$GlobalConstant.EmptyString}, or {!$GlobalConstant.Null} to the assignment I get a validation error.  If I leave the assignment field empty, then it doesn't do anything to the date. Below is a picture of my options.

[image: No Options for Null Date]

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If leaving the date field blank does not work, I would update some flag that triggers a workflow which would set the date to Null and the flag to false again.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is move this from an already working Trigger, to something more Point & Click.  It's easy to null the value of the date in the Trigger, why Salesforce doesn't let you do it in Flow is beyond me.  I'm not going to go jumping through hoops though to get this to work.

Comment: Yea, you would not need a trigger. Just update a flag field in your flow, and kind of watch over it in a workflow. When the flag is set, just null the date and  set the flag field back to false.