# How to erase date value in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I created a Flow that sets actual completion date (today's date) into the corresponding stage date field(s) when Stage is changed. At the same time, it's not erasing the value when I assign a blank value for the date field in case stage goes backwards. Any clues? It's not letting me to set the value to null or empty string either.
[image: assign a blank value for the date field]
* `{!BlankDate}` is a constant of date type with blank value. I've tried to assign value to blank date variable also with no success.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to type "Empty" on the input field? It should show a global constant with that name.

Comment: I did, EmptyString only available for Text type.

Comment: It appears not to be possible to assign a null value to a date field using visual flow. You can, however, do this with a workflow rule or a trigger. - 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106643/visual-flow-how-to-set-date-field-to-null-blank

Comment: @RenatoOliveira This is workaround, I was hoping that Salesforce betting hard on "No Coding" development is capable to deliver the missing pieces in functionality, which is not happening. I know how to do that with WF, Triggers, just wanted to see if Process Builder in connection with invocable methods and Flows can be used and it is still having issues not allowing us to rely on just declarative development tools - [Adding Clicks not Code Extensibility to Apex with Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/04/adding-clicks-not-code-extensibility-to-your-apex-with-lightning-flow.html)

Comment: The logic is complex (well, not that complex but there are multiple branches), even for 4 + 1 final stages

Answer (score 0):

If you do a record update and leave the field value blank, a null value will be inserted into the field.

This is a problem when you're trying to update the field with a formula, because there is no way to use a formula to have a null date output. If that is the case then you might need to have a split to two different record updates.

Comment: This is exactly what I expected but it's no happening - second assignment line on the screenshot has a blank value but the date does not get erased.

Comment: I've had issues during testing where a flow will run through the most recent version once and then run through the active version. So my active version kept overwriting my test. Might be that. Or some totally different automation that also runs

Comment: There is a setting allowing admins to run the most recent version, even inactive. I was also activating the most recent Flow version, to be sure. This project is in development and there is no other automations.