# How can I identify whether a picklist allows free text dynamically?

Tags: apex, schema

When iterating through fields in an object using the Schema methods, I can identify whether a field is a picklist. How do I tell if this field allows input of free text?

For example, Task.Subject is a picklist. It allows free text input.:

[image: Note the pencil symbols for allowing text input]

If I use:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Schema.SObjectType.Task.fields.Subject; 
system.debug(dfr);
```

..then I can see that isRestrictedPicklist=false. I can't see any way here to identify that free text is allowed.

Please note - I am iterating through fields, so I am looking to identify this dynamically (given a field that is a picklist as a DescribeFieldXX, identify if it allows free text input).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine if the field happens to be this one single magical type (a picklist that allows free text) by looking at the DisplayType:

```
Schema.DisplayType fieldType = Schema.SObjectType.Task.fields.Subject.getType();
if(fieldType == Schema.DisplayType.COMBOBOX) {
  // Picklist that allows free text
} else {
  // Something else
}
```

As far as I know, this is literally the only field in Salesforce that uses this DisplayType. You can read more about the [DisplayType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm) for the available types that `getType` can return.

Comment: how this combobox type can be defined? I'm aware of the existence of unrestricted picklists, but they do not let users to input a free text, you just can load values, different from the picklist's options.

Comment: @o-lexi It cannot be duplicated solely in configuration. It is a special data type used only by this one field. You might want to [vote on this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqlq).

Comment: Ohh, this is a task subject - I knew this. Thanks, and voted! 
I apologize in advance for asking this - any chance you could provide an expert advice on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222209/how-to-erase-date-value-in-flow) or [that](https://andyinthecloud.com/2018/04/30/adding-clicks-not-code-extensibility-to-your-apex-with-lightning-flow/comment-page-1/#comment-17614). Feel free to ignore this request.

Comment: Thanks - I'm sure when I was iterating through the fields (using the DisplayType checks you mentioned) this was flagging as a picklist. Still, this explains it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird edge case. I think they changed Subject into a picklist to allow a picklist of preset values. But it still supports freely entered values. So it's presenting in metadata like an unrestricted picklist (normally presents as a picklist in UI but you can enter free text when filling it by non-UI methods).

If you can't find a way to distinguish those two scenarios in metadata you might just have to treat it as a "special exception".